# Remove current object by index inside _.each with underscore

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object like so:

```
var depositOptions = {
  0 : {name: 'Monthly'},
  1 : {name : 'Standard'},
  2 : {name: 'Full' },
  3 : {name: 'Low' }
};
```

I need to remove the object where `name = 'Standard'` so I'm iterating over it using Underscore.js `_.each` until I find it, and storing the index.

```
_.each(depositOptions, function(option, i) {
      if (option.name === 'Standard') {
        // delete the object at index i
        console.log(i)
      }
    });
```

So I want to remove the option when it finds `standard` - what is the easiest way to do this?

1) Remove it inside the `_.each` loop, when `standard` is found? (Therefore no need for the index)
2) Store the index of the object I want to remove, and then delete it after I've finished iterating? (This I am finding difficult because how do I get the index outside of the loop?)
3) Start creating a new array as I iterate over `depositOptions` so that a new array is built without `standard` included

When I say I want to delete it, I want it completely gone. So not just `undefined` like using `delete` does.

Comment: Do you want to mutate the original object, or create a new filtered one?

Comment: `delete` would not set it to undefined.

Comment: If a `key` or `property` does not exist in an object, when you access it then you are going to get `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.filter` or `_.reject` instead. It wouldn't be clear to use `_.each`. Notice that these return a new array.

```
var newArray = _.filter(depositOptions, function(option) {
  return option.name !== 'Standard';
});
```

Also it looks like you have an object, not an array. Here is an array:

```
var depositOptions = [
  {name: 'Monthly'},
  {name : 'Standard'},
  {name: 'Full' },
  {name: 'Low' }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_.without` function to eliminate the key which you don't need

```
var depositOptions = {
  0 : {name: 'Monthly'},
  1 : {name : 'Standard'},
  2 : {name: 'Full' },
  3 : {name: 'Low' }
};


depositOptions = _.without(depositOptions, _.findWhere(depositOptions, {
  name: 'Standard'
}));


console.log(depositOptions);
```

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return new object with filtered properties you can use `Object.keys()` and `reduce()` in plain javascript.

```js
var depositOptions = {
  0 : {name: 'Monthly'},
  1 : {name : 'Standard'},
  2 : {name: 'Full' },
  3 : {name: 'Low' }
};

var result = Object.keys(depositOptions).reduce(function(r, k) {
  if (depositOptions[k].name != 'Standard') r[k] = depositOptions[k]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best way to do that using underscore is `_reject`.

**Usage -**

```
_.reject(depositOptions, function(val){ return val.name == 'Standard'; });
```

**Option 3 is definitely not** an option because you using exclusion method, where you are trying to fetch all other elements apart from the one you want & make use of the element you want. Too dirty for your implementation!

**Option 2 is better than option 3 but not ideal** because you have found the element & your still wasting your time iterating over others

**Option 1 with a tweak is the best solution** from the options given - small tweak includes **add a break statement** within the if statement & after you store the element. This way your just iterating till you find the element.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, you either mutate your original object or you create a new object without the unwanted key-value pair. All examples are in plain ES6, but you can easily use lodash methods. They will exclude all matches not just the first match.

Mutation. Uses [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const depositOptions = {
  0: {
    name: 'Monthly'
  },
  1: {
    name: 'Standard'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Full'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Low'
  }
};
for (let key of Object.keys(depositOptions)) {
  if (depositOptions[key].name === 'Standard') {
    delete depositOptions[key];
  }
}
console.log(depositOptions);
```

Create new object without the reference to the unwanted object.

```js
const depositOptions = {
  0: {
    name: 'Monthly'
  },
  1: {
    name: 'Standard'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Full'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Low'
  }
};
const depositOptionsFiltered = {};
for (let key of Object.keys(depositOptions)) {
  if (depositOptions[key].name !== 'Standard') {
    depositOptionsFiltered[key] = depositOptions[key];
  }
}
console.log(depositOptionsFiltered);
```

You may even want a new object and the key-value object to be a copy of the original rather than references to them. In this case you can perform a shallow copy. Uses [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const depositOptions = {
  0: {
    name: 'Monthly'
  },
  1: {
    name: 'Standard'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Full'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Low'
  }
};
const depositOptionsFiltered = {};
for (let key of Object.keys(depositOptions)) {
  if (depositOptions[key].name !== 'Standard') {
    depositOptionsFiltered[key] = Object.assign({}, depositOptions[key]);
  }
}
console.log(depositOptionsFiltered);
```